# Cindy spins this spinner 300 times. work out an estimate for the number of times that Cindy will get L?

Tags: probability

I spin a spinner 80 times.

### The table shows information about the results

### Outcome/Frequency

J       /       39

K        /          25

### L         /         16

Cindy spins this spinner 300 times.

work out an estimate for the number of times that Cindy will get L?

--

How do I solve this? I can't get my head around the formula. Can someone explain with the answer, please?

Comment: **Hint:** Use the given table to get an estimate for the probability of getting an L. Then to work out the expected number of L's from 300 spins, use $$\text{Expected L's}=300\times\text{Prob}(\text{getting an L})$$

Comment: elcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: thanks, John - what would be the value of Probability in my case? Expected L's=300× ?(Prob)

Comment: The empirical probability of getting an L is the number of L's/number of trials. The number of trials is 80.